# Use Spark to group by consecutive same values of one column, taking Max or Min value of another column for each group

Tags: apache-spark

Suppose I have a following data frame

```
+-------------------+------+------------+
|               Date|   Val|   Condition|
+-------------------+------+------------+
|2020-10-02 10:00:00|211.39|         Max|
|2020-10-02 10:10:00|210.94|         Min|
|2020-10-02 10:30:00|209.21|         Max|
|2020-10-02 11:20:00|207.48|         Min|
|2020-10-02 11:50:00|207.22|         Min| <- take only this row because it's less than 207.48
|2020-10-02 12:10:00|207.58|         Max|
|2020-10-02 12:40:00|207.45|         Min|
|2020-10-02 13:10:00|207.45|         Min| <- take either row becase they are equal
|2020-10-02 13:40:00| 208.7|         Max| <- take only this row because it's greater than 208.31
|2020-10-02 14:10:00|208.31|         Max| 
|2020-10-02 14:20:00|208.16|         Min|
|2020-10-02 14:30:00| 208.3|         Max|
|2020-10-02 14:50:00|208.25|         Min|
|2020-10-02 15:10:00| 208.7|         Max|
|2020-10-02 15:30:00|208.08|         Min|
|2020-10-02 16:00:00| 208.0|         Min| <- take only this row because it's less than 208.08
|2020-10-02 16:30:00|208.35|         Max|
|2020-10-02 16:40:00|208.26|         Min|
|2020-10-02 16:50:00|208.27|         Max|
|2020-10-02 17:30:00|208.06|         Min|
+-------------------+------+------------+
```

How can I group it by consecutive values of `Condition`, taking max or min value of `Val` for each group? (e.g. the resulting data frame should be something like the one below)
(see comments in the above data frame).

```
+-------------------+------+------------+
|               Date|   Val|   Condition|
+-------------------+------+------------+
|2020-10-02 10:00:00|211.39|         Max|
|2020-10-02 10:10:00|210.94|         Min|
|2020-10-02 10:30:00|209.21|         Max|
|2020-10-02 11:50:00|207.22|         Min|
|2020-10-02 12:10:00|207.58|         Max|
|2020-10-02 12:40:00|207.45|         Min|
|2020-10-02 13:40:00| 208.7|         Max|
|2020-10-02 14:20:00|208.16|         Min|
|2020-10-02 14:30:00| 208.3|         Max|
|2020-10-02 14:50:00|208.25|         Min|
|2020-10-02 15:10:00| 208.7|         Max|
|2020-10-02 16:00:00| 208.0|         Min|
|2020-10-02 16:30:00|208.35|         Max|
|2020-10-02 16:40:00|208.26|         Min|
|2020-10-02 16:50:00|208.27|         Max|
|2020-10-02 17:30:00|208.06|         Min|
+-------------------+------+------------+
```

The goal is:

- for each group where there are more than one consecutive row with Condition = Max or Condition = Min
- to take only one row from each group (which one - is determined by the value of Condition - it's either a row with maximum or minimum value of column Val)

Comment: You can try to group by row_number divided by 2 (rounded number)

Comment: @madprogrammer bit confused with your output DF. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @SathiyanS i edited the question, tried to make it less confusing

Comment: The ask of question is such that It cannot be parallelized , although  `Window.orderBy("Date")` might give expected results, but this will only utilise 1 core and will not scale with larger data. @madprogrammer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```scala
    val wind = Window.orderBy("Date")
        val df1 = df.withColumn("val1", when($"Condition" === lead($"Condition", 1).over(wind),
          when($"Condition" === "Min", min($"val").over(wind.rowsBetween(0,1))).otherwise(max($"val").over(wind.rowsBetween(0,1))))
            .when($"Condition" === lag($"Condition", 1).over(wind),
              when($"Condition" === "Min", min($"val").over(wind.rowsBetween(-1,0))).otherwise(max($"val").over(wind.rowsBetween(-1,0))))
          .otherwise($"val"))
    
        val df2 = df1.withColumn("rn", when($"Condition" === lead($"Condition", 1).over(wind),1)
          .when($"Condition" === lag($"Condition", 1).over(wind), 2)
          .otherwise(1)).withColumn("Val", $"val1").filter($"rn" === 1).drop("rn", "val1")
    
        df2.show(false)

    +-------------------+------+---------+
    |Date               |Val   |Condition|
    +-------------------+------+---------+
    |2020-10-02 10:00:00|211.39|Max      |
    |2020-10-02 10:10:00|210.94|Min      |
    |2020-10-02 10:30:00|209.21|Max      |
    |2020-10-02 11:20:00|207.22|Min      |
    |2020-10-02 12:10:00|207.58|Max      |
    |2020-10-02 12:40:00|207.45|Min      |
    |2020-10-02 13:40:00|208.7 |Max      |
    |2020-10-02 14:20:00|208.16|Min      |
    |2020-10-02 14:30:00|208.3 |Max      |
    |2020-10-02 14:50:00|208.25|Min      |
    |2020-10-02 15:10:00|208.7 |Max      |
    |2020-10-02 15:30:00|208.0 |Min      |
    |2020-10-02 16:30:00|208.35|Max      |
    |2020-10-02 16:40:00|208.26|Min      |
    |2020-10-02 16:50:00|208.27|Max      |
    |2020-10-02 17:30:00|208.06|Min      |
    +-------------------+------+---------+
```

Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, it is helpful. Meanwhile I managed to get another solution which also seems to work, see my own answer for it. Since I am kinda new to Spark, it would be nice if you could comment on it, in case you see any problems.

Comment: I found that both your and my solution pick up a wrong Date (e.g. for row with Val 207.22 it should be 2020-10-02 11:50:00 instead of 2020-10-02 11:20:00)

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by preparing extra column with group number for rows with the same condition in consecutive rows ("group" column in query below).

```scala
val numOfPartitions = <set numer of partitions>
val window = Window.orderBy("Date")

df
  .withColumn("condition_change", when(col("Condition") === lag("Condition", 1, false).over(window), 0).otherwise(1))
  .withColumn("group", sum("condition_change").over(window))
  .drop("condition_change")
  .repartition(numOfPartitions)
  .groupBy("group")
  .agg(
    min(struct("Val", "Date")) as "min",
    max(struct("Val", "Date")) as "max",
    first("Condition") as "Condition")
  .withColumn("result", when(col("Condition") === "Min", col("min")).otherwise(col("max")))
  .select(col("result.Date") as "Date", col("result.Val") as "Val", col("Condition"))
  .show()
```

Note that you have to set `numOfPartitions` for repartition (otherwise task will run on one executor), select value matching amount of data you have, first try can be value of "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions".

Comment: This seems inaccurate. If the condition remains the same for an identical number of consecutive rows, for two different cases, the group variable will wrongly assign the same group number to these.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution, it's in no way optimized, and probably could be improved, but seems to give correct results

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w1 = Window.orderBy("Date")
val w2 = Window.orderBy("Date")
  .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
val w3 = Window.partitionBy("cumsum").orderBy(lit(1))

val grpExtrema = extrema
.withColumn("dupe", when(lag("Condition", 1).over(w1) !== extrema("Condition"), 1).otherwise(0))
.withColumn("cumsum", sum("dupe").over(w2))
.drop("dupe")

grpExtrema
.withColumn("row", row_number.over(w3))
.withColumn("Val",
            when($"Condition" === lit("min"), min("Val").over(w3))
            .otherwise(max("Val").over(w3)))
.where(col("row") === 1).select("Date", "Val", "Condition")
.show()
```